# javascript: выделение подстроки из строки, так чтобы подстрока содержала N слов

Tags: javascript, строки, поиск, подстрока, выделение-текста

Приветствую,

подскажите, как можно быстро (может быть с помощью регулярных выражений) решить следующую задачу:

есть некоторая строка, например "жили были дед да баба, ели кашу с молоком"

1) нужно выделить из нее начиная с заданной позиции подстроку, которая содержала бы 3 слова,

например, с позиции pos = 7 должно получиться

"ыли дед да"

с позиции pos = 11 должно получиться

"дед да баба"

2) желательно, чтобы если позиция приходится на середину слова, то слово попадало бы целиком,

например с позиции pos = 7 должно получиться

"были дед да"

3) если до конца строки от позиции остаётся меньше слов, то выводится меньше слов

4) знаки препинания словами не считаются, но в подстроку входят

Это все можно реализовать по тупому, анализируя побуквенно строку в обе стороны, но хотелось бы сделать более правильно, более компактно

Comment: Возможный алгоритм: 1) кусаем на 2 части по заданной позиции; 2) Split первой части, последний элемент плюсим в начало второй части; 3) Split второй части; 4) Redim Preserve массива до нужного количества элементов; 5) Join массива.

Comment: @Akina, кхм, использовать разбиение через разделители и склейку - интересное и простое решение, надо будет попробовать на работоспособность, интересно еще - можно ли эту же задачу в одну строчку через регулярку сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const text = "жили были дед да баба, ели кашу с молоком";

pos.onchange = e => console.log(
  pos.value,
  text.match(
    new RegExp(`.{${pos.value-1}}([^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+(\\s+|$))`)
  )[1]
)
```

```html
<input id="pos" type="numer" value="7" />
```

```js
const text = "жили были дед да баба, ели кашу с молоком";

pos.onchange = e => console.log(
  pos.value,
  text.substr(pos.value - 1, text.length)  
    .split(/\s+/)
    .slice(0,3)
    .join(' ')
)
```

```html
<input id="pos" type="numer" value="7" />
```

Comment: интересный результат - но Pos =  9 и pos = 11 в первом примере дают странные результаты (почему-то в первом случае меньше, чем во втором)

Comment: @Zhihar поясните? У меня 9 - `и дед да` 11 - `дед да баба,`, вроде подходит под условие.

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал способ, предложенный @Akina:

```
    var part1 = text.substring(0, pos);
    var part2 = text.substring(pos);

    var array1 = part1.split(" ");
    var array2 = part2.split(" ");

    var subarray1 = array1.slice(array1.length - 1, array1.length);
    var subarray2 = array2.slice(0, 3);

    var newText = subarray1.join(" ") + subarray2.join(" ");
```

Работает все замечательно, но все таки это 7 строчек + может потребоваться добавить код, что если позиция указывает не на цифру или букву (например, пробел или знаки препинания), то надо брать все 3 слова спереди и ни одного сзади, но это мелочи.

Comment: Из второго снипетта из моего ответа возьмите лучше `.split(/\s+/)` вместо вашего `.split(" ")`, поскольку между словами может быть не один пробел, а больше, или табуляция.